# fastest web server for static, dynamic content?

Tags: httpd, web

I'm looking for the fastest http server available for:

1. serving static content -- huge set of large images.  Minimal features need, just as fast as possible.
2. dispatching dynamic content plugins -- think a web server that does on-the-fly watermarking or image transcoding.  I'm looking for the fastest, lowest-overhead way of dispatching this.

Environment: linux or OS/X.  any language acceptable.

Comment: why does the water-marking have to be "on-the-fly"? Couldn't images be processed server-side *outside* the webapp to add/remove the watermark, and then just serve the proper image to the site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> serving static content -- huge set of large images. Minimal features need, just as fast as possible.

[nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) is the [current favored choice](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2009/10/17/october_2009_web_server_survey.html). [LigHTTPd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) still works fine, but is less actively developed nowadays. [LiteSpeed](http://litespeedtech.com/) is also a good choice, and may be the best if you want commercial support or a nicer GUI. All of these are very fast, raw speed will not be a meaningful competitive differentiator within this group of webservers.

> dispatching dynamic content plugins -- think a web server that does on-the-fly watermarking or image transcoding. I'm looking for the fastest, lowest-overhead way of dispatching this.

Hmnn, a custom extension [module to nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx3rdPartyModules) is the lowest overhead option. But writing modules in C / C++ is *seriously* time-consuming. OP says "any language acceptable", well, if that is so then nginx with a C extension, or maybe Apache with a C extension to benefit from Apache's richer set of modules and documentation.

But realistically, who writes C code today for non-mass-market products? I would consider [Python code with Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), or a similar event-driven webserver in a high-level language to be a better match.

Comment: C or C++ is no problem... my current code base is a C-level apache module.

Comment: In that case, I'd imagine that a port to nginx wouldn't be the end of the world.

Comment: @Mark: Well, in that case, have a look at the 3rd party modules for nginx that I linked to above, for inspiration... And do the math of course, while nginx is fast, it may not be so much faster that it justifies porting over code that already works on Apache.

Comment: @Mark: See this presentation on nginx internals: http://www.slideshare.net/joshzhu/nginx-internals

It was linked from this so-so thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/86674/why-is-nginx-so-fast

Answer (score 3):

NGINX http://nginx.net for requirement 1) static file serving at least.

SEE [Why is Nginx so fast?](https://serverfault.com/questions/86674/why-is-nginx-so-fast)

Answer (score 2):

Choose between [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) and [nginx](http://nginx.net/) for static content. Choose [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org) with modules that do in-house fastcgi process management efficiently (*mod_fcgid*, *mod_wsgi*, *mod_passenger*) for generating the dynamic content.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be nginx + php-fpm + apc.  It'll handle static content and it'll handle dynamic content pretty f'ing quickly, too.

It's also worth noting that nginx has plugins, as well, and you could always write a plugin  that did the watermarking.  Doing it that way is probably the fastest possible way, although not the simplest to build.

Here's an example module that uses libgd:
http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpImageFilterModule

There's no reason you couldn't modify it to spit out watermarked images instead...

Answer (score 1):

My faster Web Server podium is :

1) Nginx

2) Lighttpd

3) Cherokee

Here some benchmark : 
http://www.cherokee-project.com/benchmarks.html

http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/lighttpd-and-cherokee-benchmark/

http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/pylons-benchmark-various-servers/

Cherokee is fast and simple to configure, for this maybe is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [lighttpd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighttpd), but I'm not sure about the watermark part.

Comment: Watermarking would be passed off to an external process, I'd imagine (or hope).  I used to use lighttpd a lot, but I'm not a huge fan of it any more, I think nginx has taken over it's niche.

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about the fastest/easiest web server **to setup**, i'd point to [HFS File Server](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) .  It doesn't support anything but static content, but its SOOOO easy to use.